# Why does my manifest.xml keep deleting the changes I make when I put the program into an apk

Tags: android, manifest

EDIT: STILL NEED HELP >:( Logcat added, as well as the manifest fix I can use for emulators only but not physical devices.  If I transfer file to APK and load onto my device the manifest.xml file for that project just reverts to the second copy of the manifest.xml file.

I had this code working literally 5 minutes ago where the whole app would run a welcome screen, 6 different "flash cards", and an exit screen with button transitions.  Now all of a sudden if I push any button the app crashes.  Just says app has stopped working unexpectedly.  I would put the logcat, but the error message is always dealing with the activity missing in the manifest.  I am getting frustrated and just want to sleep.

logcat I get for the bottom manifest file that it always goes to.  If it manually add the others then I do not get it.  DOES NOT WORK WHEN TURNING PROJECT INTO APK FORMAT

```
11-04 05:29:01.912: D/gralloc_goldfish(819): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-04 05:29:04.302: D/AndroidRuntime(819): Shutting down VM
11-04 05:29:04.302: W/dalvikvm(819): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.androidassignment2/com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.example.androidassignment2.Startup$1.onClick(Startup.java:22)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 05:29:04.382: E/AndroidRuntime(819):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

working manifest file fix

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidassignment2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.Startup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.AndroidAssignment2.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.AndroidAssignment2.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_1" >

        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_2" >

        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_3" >

        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_4" >

        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2_5" >

        </activity>

                        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.AndroidAssignment2" >

        </activity>

                               <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.MainActivity" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

all of the activities just go away once put into apk
this happens to the manifest file after putting the project into apk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidassignment2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.Startup"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidassignment2.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.AndroidAssignment2.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.AndroidAssignment2.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT: Before and after manifests.

LOGCAT JUST SAYS ACTIVITY NOT FOUND DECLARE IN MANIFEST

Comment: Please post your mainfest and your logcat.

Comment: Post your manifest and logcat

Comment: it only happens when I do it on my nexus 7, which I cannot get it to detect on my computer even with the drivers, so the emulator is all I used to debug it.  It is fatal exception saying activity is not declared, and the manifest is at a point in progress before I even started serious work on project.

Comment: this is my first project with multiple activities if that is helpful.  my other projects all work fine on my nexus 7, and I am not sure why I cannot get the device to be detected (did drivers, bla bla).  I just got it working on the nexus 7 emulator, but the moment I tried to put it on my device again it acts like the activities do not exist?

Comment: You don't need to declare all you activities in the manifest, only the main one. And post the logcat.

Comment: No, that is wrong, every Activity has to be declared in the manifest.

Comment: And please post logcat, even if it just says that. Without logcat it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Logcat is posted, this is what happens ONLY after I turn the project into APK.  The first manifest file fixes the problem and it runs seamlessly

Comment: I am losing willpower to carry on tonight, ill give you code ninjas a few minutes to respond before I sleep and hopefully get it fixed tomorrow.

Comment: Just really perplexed as to why the manifest keeps removing my changes to it and simply refuses to let this final program I had to finish tonight just not work.

Comment: This is a bit of a 'turn it of and on again' comment, but it's worth looking at because I wasted a lot of time on eclipse's quirks. Make sure you routinely run `Project -> Clean` in eclipse when you change files like the manifest that are auto-built. This rules out eclipse being odd.

Comment: Would give you my up-vote and correct answer if you were interested in making an answer below because that 100% fixed the problem.  Thank you